# MYSQL: weird results a simple GROUP BY ORDER BY statement (showing wrong column data)

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

so i have a table for user sessions w/ both stamp_in and stamp_out (epoch) for each session

```
TABLE:    tk_sessions 
columns:  ses_id | ass_id | stamp_in | stamp_out
```

(ass_id stands for asset ID hehe)

i basically just want to retrieve the latest sessions for each asset...

So i tried this:

```
SELECT ses_id,ass_id,stamp_in,stamp_out 
    FROM tk_sessions 
    ORDER BY stamp_in DESC
```

that returns ALL the sessions in the expected descending order 
I just want to return 1 of each ass_id so i added the GROUP BY ass_id statement

```
SELECT ses_id,ass_id,stamp_in,stamp_out 
    FROM tk_sessions GROUP BY ass_id 
    ORDER BY stamp_in DESC
```

but the results are odd... 
this seems to return 1 row for each ass_id as expected, but are returning the wrong sessions (not the latest stamp_in sessions)

What gives?

*scratches head*

Comment: Is this what you are looking for:

`SELECT  ses_id,ass_id, MAX(stamp_in), stamp_out FROM tk_sessions GROUP BY ass_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by in absence of aggregate function will result in indeterminate order for your query you can use a self join by calculating the max value of `stamp_in` and join with your table so the row with highest stamp_in value will be returned for each of your asset id

```
SELECT s.*
 FROM tk_sessions s
JOIN (SELECT MAX(stamp_in) stamp_in ,ass_id FROM tk_sessions  GROUP BY ass_id ) t
ON(s.stamp_in = t.stamp_in AND s.ass_id = t.ass_id)
 ORDER BY s.stamp_in DESC
```

[*`Reference :The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: oohhh , ok .. i did try this a while ago and for some reason it returned similar results to my 2nd attempt where it was returning the wrong columns.. but i copy pasted your example and it seemed to work.. 

i'll study this, thanks mate!

Comment: @BrownChiLD you are welocme you can mark this answer as accepted